# When I mount my RAID5, there is constant activity; how can I figure out what it is?

Tags: filesystem, raid, disk, raid5

there. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit. I have a 4-disk RAID5 (3 disks, 1 spare) setup, and it's completely synced/built, and the ext4 filesystem it contains is clean. When I assemble the RAID, all is fine (that I can tell). When I mount the RAID, it mounts without error, and I can use the mounted filesystem, but when it's mounted, all 4 drives in the RAID exhibit regular activity: The indicate lights flash every second or two. Does anyone know what could be going on? What can I use to tell?

NOTE: The RAID is not rebuilding/resyncing.

Answer (score 2):

Using `iotop` I determined that it was a process called `ext4lazyinit`, which is a process that initializes a newly-created ext4 filesystem "lazily", i.e., after the filesystem is created and ready for use. The constant activity on these disks has since stopped (it took a few hours).

Comment: Same think is happening to me after mounting an ext4 RAID drive manually. The files that existed on it previously still showed up, but it had not been mounted at boot time as had occurred previously.